# How to let user choose delivery date?

Tags: checkout, magento-1, shipping, date, delivery

My website is gifting website so I need to let users select the date of delivery.
I want that selection (textbox with calendar popup) on shipping details step.
I can google for a free extension but I need to hear from someone who's already solved that issue.
I also don't want to modify core files.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There are few extensions available like

- http://www.aitoc.com/en/magentomods_delivery_date.html
- http://ecommerce.aheadworks.com/magento-extensions/delivery-date-and-notice.html

Answer (score 1):

A few additions to this based on my own experience:

Shatir's comment to the OPs question talk about kiril's solution [here](http://www.magentocommerce.com/boards/viewthread/16993/) -> This module almost works on 1.7.0.2 but the date itself isn't displayed in the order in the backend.  Rather than go through debugging this I just implemented this module;

http://ecommerce-team.com/delivery-date-and-comment.html

Quick and easy, works fine and there are some backend config settings which made it useful. If I was doing it again I'd try this one (which I never found when googling);

As a footnote - The client originally bought the [Mage-World Advanced Delivery Schedule](http://www.mage-world.com/advance-delivery-schedule-magento-extension.html) module. Whilst I'm conscious of not wanting to bad-mouth specific development houses this module really does deserve to be bad-mouthed, that's all I'll say about it. Uninstalled and deleted.