# Set minimal interval between the order and delivery date;

Tags: magento-1, shipping, shipment, delivery

I am Preparing magento for a confectionery shop that wants to sell cakes and cookies on-line.

the problem is:
                "Confectionery workers should be aware of orders at least 3 day sooner."

I should set 3 day delay time for delivery in the shop so customers can choice delivery time 3 day after the current date.
there is some descriptions in [How to let user choose delivery date?](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/5968/how-to-let-user-choose-delivery-date) that explains about adding delivery date to your shop but it doese not explains about forcing customers to chose delivery date at least 3 day after current date. 
can any one help me with a comment or a solution in this condition?

Comment: i asked about delay time for delivery, that question is about adding delivery date.

Comment: The only necessary additions over and above the other questions answers would be adding the logic for detecting "three days out" constraint.